# html5 -javascript canvas circle automatic radius

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm working on html5/canvas online stamp creation project.my code is working good for displaying top circular and bottom circular text.i have problem displaying center text.its overlapping after you type 4 letters.and I also want to increase radius of circle(including top/bottom Texts) on type of Center Text..here is my Fidddle http://jsfiddle.net/apsvaeoa/..also find the attached screenshot.[image: canvas html5/js].

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
    <style>

    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="600" height="400" style="float:left;"></canvas>
    <div style="float: left; width: 538px;">
        <label style="padding-right: 51px;">Text-Top:</label>
        <input type="text" id="text_cnv" size="40" maxlength="" />
        <button id="text_cnv3" style="visibility:hidden">
            Delete
        </button>
        <label style="padding-right: 32px;">Text-bottom:</label>
        <input type="text" id="text_cnv2" size="40" maxlength="" />
        <button id="text_cnv4" style="visibility:hidden">
            Delete
        </button>
        <label style="padding-right: 32px;">Text-horizontal:</label>
        <input type="text" id="text_horizontal"/>

    </div>
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas1').getContext('2d');
        var r = 50;
        var space = Math.PI / 12;
        ctx.font = "bold 30px Courier";
        document.getElementById('text_cnv').onkeyup = function() {
            var textLength = (this.value.length);

            if (textLength > 5) {
                radiusChaninging = r + (textLength * 3);
            } else {
                radiusChaninging = r + (textLength);
            }
            textCircle(this.value, 150, 150, radiusChaninging, space, 1);
            document.getElementById('text_cnv3').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }

        document.getElementById('text_cnv2').onkeyup = function() {
            var textLength = (this.value.length);

            if (textLength > 5) {
                radiusChaninging = r + (textLength * 3);
            } else {
                radiusChaninging = r + (textLength);
            }
            textCircle(this.value, 150, 150, radiusChaninging, space);

            document.getElementById('text_cnv4').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }

        document.getElementById('text_cnv3').onclick = function() {

            textCircle('', 150, 150, 0, space, 1);
            $("#text_cnv").val('');
        }

        document.getElementById('text_cnv4').onclick = function() {

            textCircle('', 150, 150, 0, space);
                $("#text_cnv2").val('');
        }





function  drawTextHorizontal(text, x, y,radius) {


ctx.font = "bold 30px Serif";
// ctx.textAlign = "center";

ctx.fillText(text, x, y,radius);

                ctx.restore();                  

}



var x_pos = 90;
var y_pos = 150;

document.getElementById('text_horizontal').onkeyup = function() {

var nr_w = (this.value.length);

var textLength = (nr_w);



            if (textLength > 5) {
                radiusChaninging = r + (textLength * 2);
            } else {
                radiusChaninging = r + (textLength);
            }
  drawTextHorizontal(this.value, x_pos, y_pos,radiusChaninging);
}




        function textCircle(text, x, y, radius, space, top) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, ( top ? 0 : y), 600, y);
            space = space || 0;
            var numRadsPerLetter = (Math.PI - space * 2) / text.length;
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(x, y);
            var k = (top) ? 1 : -1;

            ctx.rotate(-k * ((Math.PI - numRadsPerLetter) / 2 - space));
            for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                // alert(radius);

                ctx.save();
                ctx.rotate(k * i * (numRadsPerLetter));
                ctx.textAlign = "center";
                ctx.textBaseline = (!top) ? "top" : "bottom";
                ctx.fillText(text[i], 0, -k * (radius));
                ctx.restore();
            }
            ctx.restore();
        }



    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I got the below function from **[THIS SOURCE](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-wrap-text-tutorial/)** and I just wrapped it around into your function and it works!! Now overlapping problem is not there!

This will be your `drawTextHorizontal` function

```
function  drawTextHorizontal(text, x, y,radius) {
     ctx.font = "bold 30px Serif";
     wrapText(ctx,text,x,y,4000,1); //call this
     ctx.restore();                 
}
```

This is the `wrapText` function I got from above said source

```
function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) 
{
    var words = text.split(' ');
    var line = '';

    for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
         var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
         var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
         var testWidth = metrics.width;
         if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
               context.fillText(line, x, y);
               line = words[n] + ' ';
               y += lineHeight;
         }
         else {
               line = testLine;
         }
     }
     context.fillText(line, x, y);
}
```

Here is your **[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/apsvaeoa/2/)**

Comment: how do i make circle growing on type of center Text ?

Comment: You want to grow it or you want to wrap it inside circle until some length of text is entered??

Comment: Your updated fiddle still has a problem: For example: **Text-Top:** Now is the time, **bottom:** For all good men, **horizontal:** To come to the aid. But wrapping the text horizontal is a good idea. :-)

Comment: i want circle to grow  after Center text width increases current Circle Radius.

Comment: Oh yea!! @markE!! Checking on it!! Thanks for pointing it out!!

Comment: @glenmax!! Is there any max length of characters user can enter??

Comment: @guru after 2 characters ..eg 10

Comment: @glenmax. Am asking about maximum characters user can enter in Horizontal text??

Comment: @guru lets consider max length of horizontal text to 10

Comment: @glenmax.. Do you think circle will grow when you enter 10 characters?? What will be ideal scenario to make it grow?? because when I give max condition and keep minimum 2 chars in circle it fits inside circle actually!!